# Agregar datos de SQLite a CSV con Python

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Verán tengo esta parte de código que se encarga de consultar en una BD.

Mediante un combobox se puede seleccionar un ***ID*** existente en la base y seguidamente se aprieta el botón ***Generar CSV*** y con esto se genera un documento donde se ve una columna con el ID seleccionado.

Mi problema es que, con el mismo procedimiento no solo se debe agregar el **ID** si no también todos los demás datos en diferentes columnas.

Por Ejemplo: Al seleccionar el ***ID*** **01** en el combobox, en el CSV se debe de mostrar

> "01, Simon, Perez, Masculino, Mexico"

Cada dato en una columna. Pondría más código pero de verdad estoy perdido y es todo lo que llevo hasta el momento, Agradezco si me pudieran ayudar.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import os 
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3


root = Tk()
root.geometry("460x290")
root.config(bg="dark cyan")

#####---Generador de CSV---#####
def Datos1():    
      Combo3_info = Combo3.get()
      data = {"ID":[Combo3_info]}  
      
      archivo = pd.DataFrame(data)
      archivo.to_csv("PRUEBA_Usr.csv", mode="a", header=not os.path.isfile("Data1.csv"))
      
      
#####---Diseño---#####
Frame1 = Frame(root, bd=2, padx=10, pady=3)
Label(Frame1, text="Seleccione un ID: ", font=('Times', 14)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=10)
Combo3 = ttk.Combobox(Frame1, font=('Times', 15), width=25)
Combo3.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=20, sticky=W)

Boton1 = Button(Frame1, text="Generar CSV", width=10, command = Datos1).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, pady=10)
Frame1.place(x=20, y=40)

#####---Consulta a la DB---#####
def combo_Name():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('DB1.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    query = cur.execute('SELECT ID FROM Usuario')
    
    data = []
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        data.append(row[0])


    cur.close()
    conn.close()
    return data    

Combo3['values'] = combo_Name() 
        
root.mainloop()
```

En el CSV generado con el código de arriba se muestra esto:

[image: En el CSV generado con el código de arriba se muestra esto]

Lo que yo espero es que se muestre esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En primer lugar debes de cerrar la conexión antes de retornar el valor por que al hacer el return todo lo demás es ignorado y no tiene efecto, en segundo lugar podrías poner el resultado de tu variable `data`? No se  nada de consultas de sqlite pero si te puedo ayudar a generar el csv y quiero ayudarte

Comment: Muchas gracias por el interés @Christian , ya edité la pregunta y cambié de lugar el return como sugeriste. Añadí un ejemplo del CSV para explicarme mejor.

Comment: Haz un `print(data)` y agrega ese resultado por favor

Comment: Lo que está mal es la consulta sql, cambia por un `SELECT * FROM Usuario` y debería de funcionar

Comment: del _print(data)_  es : `[1, 2, 3]` . Lo de poner el * ya lo intenté, el problema es que no se como declarar el espacio donde va cada columna. La columna _ID_ si está declarada y por eso si se visualiza, pero las demás no.

Comment: Hazlo de la misma forma que con la column `ID`, pero es slgo raro el contenido de la variable `data`

Comment: `def Datos1():    
      Combo3_info = Combo3.get()
      data = {"ID":[Combo3_info],
              "Nombre": [""],
              "Apellido": [""],
              "Sexo":[""],
              "Pais":[""]} `   
Ya lo puse así y se en el CSV se muestra ya el nombre de las columnas pero no su contenido, se queda vacío

Comment: Exacto, pero la información de esas claves depende de la variable `data`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127376/discussion-between-christian-and-truman9084).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tenia que hacer una nueva conexión y consulta en la función ***Datos1()*** esta ves llamando a todos los datos que existen en la BD. Con el extra de agregar el valor seleccionado en el combobox.

```
def Datos1():     
      Combo3_info = Combo3.get()
      conn = sqlite3.connect('DB1.db')
      cur = conn.cursor()
      query = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Usuario where ID="+Combo3_info)
```

Luego en esa misma función se declaran variables que tomaran el dato de cada columna. El resto es simplemente ir acomodando el orden deseado a ver en el csv.

```
      resultado= cur.fetchall()
      ID = resultado[0][0]
      Nombre = resultado[0][1]
      Apellido = resultado[0][2]
      Sexo = resultado[0][3]
      Pais = resultado[0][4]
       
      cur.close()
      conn.close()
      data = {"ID":[ID], "Nombre":[Nombre], "Apellido":[Apellido], "Sexo":[Sexo], "Pais":[Pais]} 
      
      archivo = pd.DataFrame(data)
      archivo.to_csv("PRUEBA_Usr.csv", mode="a", header=not os.path.isfile("Data1.csv"))
```